# DELETE rest endpoint returns 410 Gone

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, jax-rs

I have Jersey API as follows:

```
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Result<String> delete(@HeaderParam(AUTH_TOKEN) String auth_token,
        ParamBean bean) {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.setId(bean.getId());
    service.deleteNode(auth_token, node);

    return new Result("Deleted");
}
```

When I call it from Rest Client, it works properly and delete the entry from DB.

```
http://localhost:8080/backend/api/node
```

With header

```
auth_token: 4F+qKpd58rU
```

and Param:

```
{ "id" : "0121387b-c0c0-4452-bf45-cfc4770e3b6b" }
```

But when called from angular js, it returns 410 Gone error.

and tomcat log shows:

```
[http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR c.t.c.e.h.GlobalExceptionHandler - GlobalExceptionHandler: null
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Angular JS Code:

Controller function :

```
params = {};
    params.data = {         
        "id" : h.id
    };
    params.headers = {
            auth_token : authService.session.token
    };              

    hubService.remove(params,function(data,status){
        alert(data);
    });
```

Service :

```
remove: function(params,callback)
    {
        params.url =  "http://localhost:8080/backend/api/node"
        params.method="DELETE";
        dao.call(params,function(data,status){
            callback(data,status);
        });
    },
```

DAO :

```
angular.module('httpService',[]).service("dao",function($http){
    return {
        call: function(params,callback)
        {
            var httpSetting = {};
            httpSetting.method = params.method;
            httpSetting.url = params.url;
            if(params.headers)
            {
                httpSetting.headers=params.headers;
                delete params.headers;
            }
            if(params.method==="GET") {
                httpSetting.params=params.data;
            }
            if(params.method==="POST") {
                httpSetting.data = params.data;
            }
            if(params.method==="DELETE") {
                httpSetting.data = params.data;
            }

            $http(httpSetting).success(function(data,status){
                callback(data,status);
            }).error(function(data,status){
                callback(data,status);
            });;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: May you post your `angularjs` code?

Comment: See edit, I have added controller snippet, service method and dao module

Comment: Can you also post a request sent from a browser, for example by inspecting it with Chrome Developer Tools. This should give you an idea what's being exactly sent from Angular app to the backend. Maybe `h.id` is null or undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DELETE` methods cannot take bodies.  They don't get sent over HTTP and won't be consumed by the server.